# Sign in with LinkedIn

Tags: ios

when click on linkedIn button from my app linkedIn redirect to linkedIn App 
If app is not install that time get the message please install the linkedIn.

I want to  simple SignIn with LinkedIn like google SignIn.

So please give me proper response.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [LinkedIn iOS SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk)

it provides

- Single sign-on (SSO) authentication, in conjunction with the official LinkedIn mobile application.
- A convenient wrapper for making authenticated calls to LinkedIn's REST APIs.
- Deeplinking to additional member content in the official LinkedIn iOS app.
- A sample application that demonstrates all of the SDK's features.